# What is the best way to create a menu item that links to all posts with a certain tag?

Tags: tags, menus

I guess the title says it all. Short of creating a page with a custom template that links all the posts with a given tag (this is NOT a scalable solution, particularly if you want to let a customer do this), how would you add a menu item that takes you to a tag archive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting up custom menu click `Screen Options` (top right, near `Help`) and check `Post Tags` there. You will get metabox that will allow to add links to tag archives as menu item.